# Folding/reducing w/ possibly empty Seq and no zero value

Tags: scala

As an example, in Slick, the `DDL` object can be composed:

```
val t1: DDL = Table1.ddl
val t2: DDL = Table2.ddl
val compositeDDL = t1 ++ t2
```

If I have a sequence of `DDL`s I would like to reduce them to a single `DDL` with `++`:

```
ddls.reduceLeft(_ ++ _)
```

This doesn't work if the sequence is empty. But I can't use fold either, because there's no *zero* starting value I can use (would such a value make sense?).

```
ddls.foldLeft( wot? )(_ ++ _)
```

So I resort to something like:

```
if (ddls.isEmpty) None else Some(ddls.reduceLeft(_ ++ _))
```

Is this the nicest way I can approach this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `reduceLeftOption` like this:

```
ddls.reduceLeftOption(_ ++ _)
```

It works exactly like this:

```
if (ddls.isEmpty) None else Some(ddls.reduceLeft(_ ++ _))
```

You could implement almost all `Seq` methods using `foldLeft`. For `reduceLeftOption`:

```
ddls.foldLeft(None: Option[DDL]){ (a, e) => a.map{ _ ++ e }.orElse( Some(e) ) }
```

Comment: Oh, it's been around since 2.8. *shameface*

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduceLeftOption` to get an `Option` wrapped result:

```
 ddls.reduceLeftOption(_ ++ _)
```